# Extracting the keys and values out of a list

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a string as :

```
fmt_string="I am a non-smoker female with a sum assured amount of 
1000000 and a policy term for 20 years"
```

After this I have removed the stopwords

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
d = [i for i in fmt_string.lower().split() if i not in stop]
```

Now I want my output as :

```
{'gender': 'female', 'Sum assured amount': '1000000', 'smoke': 'non-
 smoker', 'Policy term': '20'}
```

for achieving the same I ran the following code:

```
print {'smoke':d[0], 'gender':d[1], 'Sum assured amount': d[5], 
'Policy term': d[8]}
```

but in the following code I am hard coding my code and giving place values for extracting the values.
Is there a possible way where I don't need to give the exact position of the values in my list and make the code more generalized.

Comment: will the string look like this every time

Comment: no it will change

Comment: it can be something like: I am a male smoker who want to invest sum assured for 15 years of 200000 rupees

Comment: okay then you can do it based on keywords, split the senetences to words array, and you can search for keywords like (smoke <=> smoker),(male/female <=> gender) ,(years <=> years_in_number) and finally (amount/rupees <=> amoun_in_number). Now you can get their key , eventhough the sentence is in dynamic format

Comment: I thought of the same logic but can I search for such keywords?

Comment: yes you can, if "smoke" in "non-smoker" then get their key

Comment: So where should I change in code as I am new to python

Comment: You need to give a lot more examples of your input to get a reasonable answer to this question.

Comment: I have added an answer, which would be just a idea to implement @GeetanjaliBisht

Answer (score 2):

This code will work for this, sentences, you have to playaround with keywords and you also need to set some conditions to check whether the amount and years are integers and if not go for nearby integers. Just this is a way

```
def compare(s1,s2):
        slen = len(s1)
        y=0
        while y<slen:
            if s1[y] in words:
                key=words.index(s1[y])
                return key;
            else:
                key=-1
            y+=1

    fmt_string="I am a non-smoker female with a sum assured amount of 1000000 and a policy term for 20 years"
    words = fmt_string.split()
    length=len(words)
    x=0
    gen=["male","female"];
    yrs = ["years","year","annum","per annum"];
    value=["amount","rupees"]
    ske = ["smoke","smoker","non-smoker"]
    gen_value = compare(gen,words)
    yrs_value = compare(yrs,words)
    vlue_value = compare(value,words)
    ske_value = compare(ske,words)
    yrs_value= yrs_value-1;
    amount_value = vlue_value + 2;

    print {'smoke':words[ske_value], 'gender':words[gen_value], 'Sum assured amount': words[amount_value], 'Policy term': words[yrs_value]}
```

Hope you will play around with keywords..!

Comment: In the following you are keeping the yrs_value and amount_value as positional. I can something like: fmt_string = "I am a smoker male who wants a policy for 35 yrs of 2500000 rupees"
Hence my fmt_string will be dynamic

Comment: create a function to compare keyword array with the main array, then i splitted the given sentences to array which will act as main array. i started creating keyword arrays, you will have no problem with gender and smoke , since they will contain the words exactly, so build the keywords array strong, Coming to the years and amount array you have to create a array as above, but while retrieving the position you have to check whether the element is integer, if not then search for nearby element, and get the positon if it integer, then it would work perfectly, I have coded sample

Comment: you will need to build keywords strong, and you need to get position based on their type, so that the code will work perfectly @GeetanjaliBisht

Comment: So how can I check if its an integer or not for amount and age?

Comment: In python you check using in built functions like int, etc

Comment: Actually in this code the only problem I am finding is for detecting where will be my age and amount will be with the change of string. So if you can help with that it will be really helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: The solution to your problem is described in the first seven chapters of the [nltk book](http://www.nltk.org/book/).

In other words, what you are asking for is much too difficult for a beginning programmer (and much too broad a question for this site). You need full-bore information extraction, not "extracting keys and values out of a list." Basically you need to train a custom classifier for each attribute you are interested in (for which you need an annotated corpus), and some more things besides. Yes, some answers will suggest you hack something together that will work for the three made-up examples they considered, but it's unlikely they will do anything useful with real data.

I recommend you put this project aside, for the time being at least. Then study a good Python tutorial, and *then* the nltk book. (Despite their good intentions, the nltk book is not the best introduction to the language.)

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
fmt = "I am a non-smoker female with a sum assured amount of 1000000 and a policy term for 20 years"
wt = word_tokenize(fmt)
```

Now comes part of speech tagging

```
nltk.pos_tag(wt)
[('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('a', 'DT'), ('non-smoker', 'JJ'), ('female', 'NN'), ('with', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('sum', 'NN'), ('assured', 'JJ'), ('amount', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('1000000', 'CD'), ('and', 'CC'), ('a', 'DT'), ('policy', 'NN'), ('term', 'NN'), ('for', 'IN'), ('20', 'CD'), ('years', 'NNS')]
```

Then you can use list comprehension to search for what you want

```
p1 = nltk.pos_tag(wt)
[i for i, v in enumerate(p1) if v[1] == 'NN']
[4, 7, 9, 14, 15]
[i for i, v in enumerate(p1) if v[1] == 'CD']
[11, 17]
```

I suppose you will have different sentence

```
CD: numeral
JJ: adjective
```

You have only two numerals and JJ stands for non-smoker.Now it is easy to print what ever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I want my output as : {'gender': 'female', 'Sum assured amount': '1000000', 'smoke': 'non-smoker', 'Policy term': '20'}       and my string will always change so by this I am just getting the position